# consulta tablas sql y normalización

Tags: sql

Hola tengo una duda respecto a si es una práctica obligatoria hacer una tabla para cosas que no van a tener mas de 2 o 3 filas en esa tabla, por ejemplo si tengo un atributo "tipo de pedido" en mi clase pedido, y ese tipo de pedido puede ser "presupuesto" o "remito", tiene sentido tener una tabla "tipo de pedido" para solamente tener dos valores?? o simplemente puedo establecer a "tipo de pedido" como bool y en base al valor true/false, sea remito o presupuesto. que opinan??

Si bien por normalización, esa tabla deberia exisitir.. no se hasta que punto tiene sentido??

Comment: No hay _reglas obligatorias_ en el diseño de base de datos. Esto depende de la opinión/formación de cada uno.

Comment: Es decir que cualquiera de los caminos es válido?? Tanto hacer una tabla para esos valores fijos como establecer un atributo como booleano y luego “deducir” que tipo de pedido es

Comment: Considera qué posibilidades hay que, en un futuro, ese campo pueda tener más valores. Es mucho más sencillo tener esos datos en una tabla y agregar una fila más, que tener que cambiar parte de tu código porque ahora ya no sólo es 1 ó 0

Comment: Yo cuando son valores fijos que no van a variar a lo largo del tiempo, pongo un enum o un int o un bool

Comment: Realmente cualquiera de las dos formas son posibles, aunque yo personalmente me decantaría por crear la tabla. El motivo principal es la claridad. Queda mucho más claro y legible crear una tabla de mapeo con su respectiva clave foránea, aunque esta sólo tenga dos o tres registros, que estar suponiendo lo que puede o no significar un valor booleano. Por otro lado, si en algún momento quieres añadir algún otro tipo de pedido, será muchísimo más sencillo si tienes una tabla de mapeo.

Comment: @fer poner un true o false es totalmente inviable, imaginate en 1 año cuando alguien vaya a darle soporte y vea puros booleanos o cosas que no dicen nada, yo si fuera ese desarrollador te insultaria bastante, ante todo buenas practicas

Comment: @zeross si uno de los motivos que me hace plantear esta situación, es el tema de la claridad que aporta tenerlo “tabulado” sin tener que andar infiriendo sobre que tipo de pedido es..

Comment: @Bruno Sosa Fast Tag por eso consulto en el foro, para ver que opiniones me dan sobre cual seria la mejor práctica

Comment: @fer pues si es un valor es multivalorado pasarlo a otra tabla

Comment: No es obligatoria pero si una buena práctica, aunque la tabla secundaría tenga una sola fila. ¿Que ocurre si un día te piden simplemente modificar "Remito" por "Nota Remito? imagina las consecuencias de manejar esto en tu capa de aplicación versus llevarla en tu capa de datos.

Comment: Siempre diseña a futuro. Hoy hay dos tipos. Si cambia la ley/norma/proceso, ¿hay más tipos y toca quemarlos en alguna parte?